# Create a dynamic id in my html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

i take a plugin from web to create dynamic tabs. I tried to adapt the code according to my wishes but i need to create a dynamic id. Here the code :

```
function addNewStaticTab()
{
    $.addDynaTab({
        tabID : 'addstatictab',
        type : 'html',
        html : "<table class='fontStreet' width='100%'> <tr> <td align='left' class='td-label'>Intitulé*</td> <td width='2%'>&nbsp;</td> <td align='left' width='150'><input type='text' class='input-middle' required></td> <td> <figure onclick='makeCaptionAppear('figcaptionRosterInt');' style='position:relative; padding:0px; margin:0px;' ><img src='img/inter.png' id='buttonCriteresLeft'><figcaption class='figcaptionRoster2' id='figcaptionRosterInt' onMouseOut='makeCaptionDisappear('figcaptionRosterInt');'>Aide:<br> Exemples d'intitulés :<br>Projet, développement commercial, développement international, En création, prestataire, apporteur d'affaires, recherche d'emploi/opportunités, etc.</figcaption></figure> </td> </tr> </table>",
        params : {},
        tabTitle : 'NOUVELLE ACTIVITÉ'
    });
}
```

Where the id is "**figcaptionRosterInt**" i need to change it to a dynamic id. As you can see i call a fonction to open an another div popup who needs IDs but even if the window is the same in other tabs, the id need to be unique..

I don't know if you understand, sorry for my english.

thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you can achieve this by adding a `parameter` to the 
`addNewStaticTab` function

```
function addNewStaticTab(parameter_id)
{
    $.addDynaTab({
        tabID : 'addstatictab',
        type : 'html',
        html : "<table class='fontStreet' width='100%'> <tr> <td align='left' class='td-label'>Intitulé*</td> <td width='2%'>&nbsp;</td> <td align='left' width='150'><input type='text' class='input-middle' required></td> <td> <figure onclick='makeCaptionAppear('+ parameter_id +');' style='position:relative; padding:0px; margin:0px;' ><img src='img/inter.png' id='buttonCriteresLeft'><figcaption class='figcaptionRoster2' id='+ parameter_id +' onMouseOut='makeCaptionDisappear('+ parameter_id +');'>Aide:<br> Exemples d'intitulés :<br>Projet, développement commercial, développement international, En création, prestataire, apporteur d'affaires, recherche d'emploi/opportunités, etc.</figcaption></figure> </td> </tr> </table>",
        params : {},
        tabTitle : 'NOUVELLE ACTIVITÉ'
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I tried it but it doesn't work..It seems there are some problems with my function. Here it is : 

// make help caption appear
function makeCaptionAppear(id){
 
 get(id).style.display="block";

}

Comment: It's look like the problem is in the "concatenation". I'm sorry i'm too bad :(

Comment: try this : makeCaptionAppear('"+ parameter_id +"')